# Maven Java EE Configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

In my maven project, I have this Effective POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>spring</groupId>
  <artifactId>example</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>example</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>C:\Users\Kleber\Downloads\Projetos\example\src\main\java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>C:\Users\Kleber\Downloads\Projetos\example\src\main\scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>C:\Users\Kleber\Downloads\Projetos\example\src\test\java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>C:\Users\Kleber\Downloads\Projetos\example\target\classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>C:\Users\Kleber\Downloads\Projetos\example\target\test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>C:\Users\Kleber\Downloads\Projetos\example\src\main\resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>C:\Users\Kleber\Downloads\Projetos\example\src\test\resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>C:\Users\Kleber\Downloads\Projetos\example\target</directory>
    <finalName>example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
          <server>TomcatServer</server>
          <path>/webappExample</path>
          <username>user001</username>
          <password>123</password>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-war</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>war</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>C:\Users\Kleber\Downloads\Projetos\example\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>C:\Users\Kleber\Downloads\Projetos\example\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>C:\Users\Kleber\Downloads\Projetos\example\target\site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>C:\Users\Kleber\Downloads\Projetos\example\target\site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

In this moment, in the Markers tab on my Eclipse IDE, this error is being presented:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Dynamic Web Module 3.0 requires Java 1.6 or newer.  example     line 1  Maven Java EE Configuration Problem
One or more constraints have not been satisfied.    example     line 1  Maven Java EE Configuration Problem
```

I try fix this configuration in the Build path from my project (In Properties/Java Build Path), but when I run Maven > Update Project, the value for this option returned to the previous one.

Where I should change this option to fix this error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error abotut dynamic web module version reported by STS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483637/error-abotut-dynamic-web-module-version-reported-by-sts)

Comment: I did what was suggest on this topic, and an NullPointerException was triggered.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

1. Go to project `Build Path` and change the Java Library version to `1.7`
2. Go to Eclipse Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Change compliance level to `1.7`
3. Right click on project -> Properties -> Project Facets
4. Uncheck `Dynamic Web Module` and click **Apply** (also uncheck `JavaServer Faces` if you had that)
5. Change the `Java` facet version to `1.7` and click **Apply**
6. Add the `Dyanmic Web Module v3.0`, apply.

Eclipse's facets configuration is buggy. Make sure you keep hitting `Apply` between checking and unchecking of facets.

**Links:**

[Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122336/cannot-change-version-of-project-facet-dynamic-web-module-to-3-0)

[Change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 2.5](https://www.myeclipseide.com/PNphpBB2-viewtopic-t-29707.html)

Comment: Thanks,I did what you mentioned here, could change it to version 3.0  but even after closing, opening, cleaning and building the project the error messages did not go. So I just right clicked on them to remove them manually. Now the project works ! thanks to buggy Eclipse this bug  wasted 3 hours of my time!

Comment: I had 1 and 2 above in place. The only change I made was the Java facet version and that seems to have done it for me. The Dynamic Web Module seemed to be taking over from Maven so I left it out. All good now, thanks.

Answer (score 29):

GGrec's solution doesn't work for me. I manage to fixed this issue by adding to pom.xml this:

```
<build>
     <finalName>finalName</finalName>
     <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source> <!-- yours Java version -->
                <target>1.8</target> <!-- yours Java version -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

UPDATE:
In addition I figured out that everytime you run mvn install command on this pom.xml it overrides previous configuration. The right solution is either remove this version from pom.xml and set it up in eclipse options or just use configuration from pom.xml.

Comment: This works for me after doing the "right click on Project > Maven > Update Project"

Comment: Only adding this line:

<version>3.1</version>

worked for me; the workspace built automatically after saving pom.xml and then the error disappeared.

Answer (score 7):

After following above troubleshooting steps. Update your maven project.

> Right click on your project--> Maven--> Update Project
>
> Or simply Alt+f5.

Hope this might help someone.

Answer (score 5):

Also as Kefas I am specify java version to 1.7 and it works!

```
 <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
         <source>1.7</source> 
         <target>1.7</target> 
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

This might sound silly but I just did Project->Clean and then Maven->Update.

Solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The above suggests is helpful for me!
Right click on project -> Properties -> Project Facets, then change the Java facets version to 1.7.

If it doesn't work, add the following code to pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <finalName>finalName</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source> <!-- yours Java version -->
                <target>1.7</target> <!-- yours Java version -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Save pom.xml.

And then, right click on project-->Maven-->Update Project.

Answer (score 1):

Changed version to 3.1 and the tags  and  to 1.7

```
 <plugin>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.1</version>
<configuration>
     <source>1.7</source> 
     <target>1.7</target> 
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using java 1.8. Fixed doing the following.

Remove from pom:

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

It will complain that pom is not up to date.
Used quick fix to update then you get a whole bunch of errors.

RE-ADD to pom:

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Updated maven and all errors are cleared.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                    <warName>mfp</warName>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <finalName>myprojectname</finalName>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to reset maven settings in Window->Preferences->Maven-> User Settings to "C:\Development\apache-maven-3.5.3\conf\settings.xml".

Answer (score 0):

The Right Answer is  : - Just a Simple thing 
Most of times you cant change the Dynamic Web Module Version to 3.0 .. it must be default set to 2.3 or 2.4 or else. Its not gonna work 
         right click on project-> preference -> project facet -> uncheck dynamic web module and change the version to 3.0 then check it. and i think you have to change the latest version for ( i.e: 1.7 or higher ) that . after that click apply and close button.

then update the maven project.. right click on project select maven -> update project.
still the error will continue for  80% of us..

The Real Solution is here
1> go to you work space folder
2> then go to your project folder
3> check for .settings file (sometimes it may be hidden then unhide it..(so rare chance )
4> Go into that .settings file then check for org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml file and edit with notepad++ or some thing like that..enter code here
5>this is the code inside that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faceted-project>
  <fixed facet="wst.jsdt.web"/>
  <installed facet="java" version="1.5"/>
  <installed facet="jst.web" version="2.4"/>
  <installed facet="wst.jsdt.web" version="1.0"/>
</faceted-project>
```

change the jst.web version to 3.0 like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faceted-project>
  <fixed facet="wst.jsdt.web"/>
  <installed facet="java" version="1.5"/>
  <installed facet="jst.web" version="3.0"/>
  <installed facet="wst.jsdt.web" version="1.0"/>
</faceted-project>
```

then finally update the maven .. then restart the eclipse or another IDE

Answer (score 0):

I have added below line of code in pom.xml and it worked.

```
<properties>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: You can see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16846