# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes.<init>

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, nosuchmethoderror

After migrating from Spring 3 to Spring 4, I get the following error when I request a page:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes.<init>(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V
```

I double checked and the method does not seem to exist in Spring 4. I wonder if I messed up some xsd versions in my `web.xml` or my `dispatcher-servlet.xml`

Here is my `web.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">


  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
      org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

`dispatcher-servlet.xml`:

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">  

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.javacms.controllers" />

  <mvc:resources mapping="/templates/**" location="/templates/" />

  <!--  added to avoid exceptions -->
  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />

  <!-- JSTL view resolver -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/templates/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And my `pom.xml`:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>javacms</groupId>
  <artifactId>javacms</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>javacms Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <spring.version>4.1.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring-security.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Spring security -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
          <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>


        <!-- MySQL connector --> 
        <dependency>
          <groupId>mysql</groupId>
          <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
          <version>5.1.36</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate --> 
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
          <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>WebApp</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Am I missing a dependency or do I have some wrong versions?

Comment: Are you sure that required jars are present in your classpath?

Comment: under Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Maven Dependencies, all jars that are defined in the pom are listed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes.<init>(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V` means that you are using the latest version of spring and you are trying to invoke older version `ServletRequestAttributes` from Spring 3.

Have a look in javadoc:
[Spring 3 - ServletRequestAttributes](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.RC2/api/org/springframework/web/context/request/ServletRequestAttributes.html#ServletRequestAttributes(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest))
[Spring 4 - ServletRequestAttributes](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/ServletRequestAttributes.html)

My guess Spring 4 uses older version of jar that contains `ServletRequestAttributes`. Check your libraries and see if there is conflict.

Try add this to pom.xml:

```
  <build>
    <finalName>WebApp</finalName>
        <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
             <source>1.7</source> 
             <target>1.7</target> 
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: All spring libraries are version 4.1.7.RELEASE and Eclipse does not show any errors

Comment: How do you run this application ? Maybe there is some old version libriary on web server that is messing around your House of Cards. Eclipse its one thing and runtime is other. Try to eradicate your libs from Spring 3 whatever you find them.

Comment: Right click on project -> Run on Server (tomcat)
I noticed the following error though: One or more  constraints have not been satisfied (Type: Maven Java EE Configuration Problem), but I cannot get any further information.

Comment: Eclipse its one thing and runtime is other. Try to eradicate your libs from Spring 3 whatever you find them.

Comment: Updated answer. Please add this to pom.xml. And again.

Comment: You can try to fix this eclipse problem with : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23183931/maven-java-ee-configuration

Comment: I just did this, these problems are solved now :) Now I cannot start Tomcat however... But I'll figure it out and see if it solved my original problem.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this version problem by using an apache httpclient's newer 4.5.9 instead of 4.5.6, Maven pom shows an overiding warning.