# Type Dynamic Web Module 3.0 requires Java 1.6 or newer, java plugin error

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, servlets

I previously i installed JRE 8. I uninstalled it and installed JRE 7 because Jasper ireport is incompatible with JRE 8. After I installed JRE 7, my current maven project has been stopped working.

Another problems appeared that appeared is "project configuration is not up to date with pom xml". I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23183931/maven-java-ee-configuration). I tried all that but nothing happened.

If you need more details, please let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add the following configuration :

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
       <source>1.7</source>
       <target>1.7</target>
       <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And right-click on your project: `Maven->Update Maven Project`

Comment: Just a note for total neophytes like me: <plugin></plugin> is a child of <plugins></plugins>, which is a child of <build></build>, inside of pom.xml.